# What is the Reference that we have to add to use the Format function in Visual Basic 6.0?

Tags: vb6, function, reference, format

I'm using VB 6.0 and it gives me:

> Compile Error:
>
> Can't Find Project or Library

in this sub:

```
Private Sub MDITimer_Timer()
    Dim textStr As String
    textStr = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    StatusBar.Panels(1).Text = textStr
End Sub
```

I made it like this and the error still was in the Format function (so it is not a `StatusBar` problem).

Can you tell me what is the Reference that we have to add to use the Format function? Or if a Reference is not needed, what do we have to do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably overloaded `Format()` with a declaration of the same name.  Have you tried calling `VBA.Format()` instead?

You should also use `Format$()` to avoid the unnecessary overhead of working with the Variant result `Format()` returns.

Comment: It was exactly this :P
althought I've solved the problem last week you've the better answer ^^

Answer (score 3):

Problem's more likely to be the StatusBar (In the Microsoft Windows Common Controls, `MSCOMCTL.ocx`). Format is built into the VB6 language, you shouldn't need any reference at all.

---

**EDIT** Format is in `VBA.Strings`. I think this is in the "Visual Basic for Applications" reference, MSVBVM60.dll. I thought the VB6 IDE prevented you from unticking the reference.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but in case someone else comes down this road...

When I had this issue found the real problem was nothing to do with MSVBVM60.dll which as said cannot be disabled as a reference.

What the error is complaining about is that a reference defined in the project is not resolved. It is not saying that the missing reference necessarily has anything to do with the function it is highlighting. What I assume the compiler is doing is sequentially searching the defined references to find the function. During that search it finds one of the references is not resolved (ie the dll or whatever is missing). This causes it to stop the search and give the error.

Reason using VBA.Format helps is that it tells the compiler where to search avoiding the need to scan through all the references.

Solution: check references defined in the project (Project => References) and make sure they are all resolved.
Usually an unresolved reference will have the word 'MISSING:' in front of it. The path shown for the reference is where the project thinks it should be, it does not mean it is there.